# Show Our Application Notification On Android Wear Device

Tags: java, android, notifications, push-notification

I want to show My Application Notification on Android Wear Device. For this i create a new notification like this

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().setHintHideIcon(true).setBackground(bmp);
    Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(msgText).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).extend(wearableExtender).build();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notif);
```

But i am getting two notification on Device. Pls anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a separate notification for android wear. Your device notification will automatically appear on android wear. In short, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: are u sure we don't need to create separate notification for android wear device??

Comment: "When an Android handheld (phone or tablet) and Android wearable are connected, the handheld automatically shares notifications with the wearable." This is the [first line in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/index.html)